# Do Not Execute another SQL Server Agent Job unless the other finishes the execution properly

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-server-agent, ssas-tabular

My requirement is to run SSIS package from SQL Server agent job, I have 3 SSIS packages 2 packages loading the data to SQL Table and 3rd package processing the cube. I have created a 2 SQL Server Agent Job, one to run the package which is loading the data to SQL table and another to process the cube.
I have tried the below solution but no is working upto the expectation as I want

---

**Solution 1**:-
Created a SQL Server Agent Job with 3 steps.

> 1st Step to execute one package.
>
> 2nd Step to execute another package.
>
> 3rd Step to execute the package which processing the cube.

**Issue**:- 1st and 2nd step executed properly but the 3rd one is not getting executed

---

**Solution 2**:-
Created a SQL Server Agent Job 3 steps.

> 1st Step to execute one package.
>
> 2nd Step to execute another package.
>
> 3rd Step to process the cube directly using XML code.

**Issue**:- Again the cube is not processing

---

**Solution 3**:-
Created a 2 SQL Server Agent Jobs, 1 which execute the package to load the data and 2nd to process the cube. Independently both works fine. To run one after another I did the below steps.

> 1st Step to execute one package.
>
> 2nd Step to execute another package.
>
> 3rd Step write the T-SQL Command to execute the Job which process the
>   cube (processing using SSIS Package).

```
Use msdb;
Go
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Job_Name' ;
GO
```

**Issue**:- again the cube job is not executing

---

**Solution 4**:-
Created a job with 1 step

Step:- T-SQL Command to execute the packages
T-SQL Command:-

```
Use msdb;
Go
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Job1_Name' ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Job2_Name' ;
GO
```

**Issue**:- Both job executing but not into the order, Cube processing package starts before the data load package ends its execution.

---

SSAS Cube is in Tabular Model

Do anybody has another approach for it?

Comment: When you tried solution 1 could you see why the cube failed to process?  Did viewing the job history show if the final step had been executed?  If an earlier step raised an error it is possible for the job to exit at that point (depending on how it is configured).

Comment: Your first three solutions are all fine.  You need to figure out why the cube is not processing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, If I go with first solution I need to process the cube default, I have a SSAS tabular model cube and getting an error like 'Cube cannot be processed when Analysis Services is in Tabular mode. Please process Database object instead.' but the same package executes separate job.

Comment: Solution 2 :-XML Script is failing to process all the dimensions and measure groups. Solution 3 and Solution 4:- execute packages successfully but the order of execution is not correct. As I mentioned cube processing starts before the data load finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution, I created one more SSIS package as 'Master package' and this package has 'Sequence container' which execute all the packages in a sequence (order which i want them to execute).

Thanks